# How to make "sort" execute and print earlier before the "awk script" completely execute so that I can add something after the sorted data?

Tags: unix, awk

So, I basically want to store sorted array/data into another array and use that data to print something else?

Even when I want to have the footer, sorted data is printed after the footer.

```
printf ("    %-25s %-20s %d\n", employee_name[working_employee_id[y]], title[employee_name[working_employee_id[y]]], salary[employee_name[working_employee_id[y]]]) | "sort -nr -k2"
```

I want to print other things after the execution of this line instead of letting sort to print at the end

Comment: please update the question with a sample set of input, a complete set of code that demonstrates the issue, the (wrong) output generated by the code and the (correct) expected output; also update the question to include the output from `awk --version`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `close()` the pipe at the end of your input before printing anything else if you want to make sure the command you're piping to finishes displaying all its output before your footer text.

Example:

```bash
$ paste <(seq 10 | shuf) <(seq 10 | shuf) |
  awk '{ printf "%d\t%d\t%d\n", $1, $2, $1 + $2 | "sort -k1,1n" }
       END { close("sort -k1,1n"); print "a\tb\tc" }'
1   8   9
2   3   5
3   6   9
4   4   8
5   2   7
6   10  16
7   9   16
8   1   9
9   7   16
10  5   15
a   b   c
```